# X86 Intel Assembly Language Questions

Tags: assembly, intel

I'm still pretty new at assembly, and I wasn't able to find an explanation anywhere that made sense of the following code? The problem I'm having is based on a homework assignment I was assigned.

```
Mov eax,11
mov ebx,24
mov ecx,7
mov edx,24
```

This is where I get lost. I understand how the first thing `MOV`. And how the first item is the destination, and the second is the source. What gets me, is following up with

```
Mul EBX
```

What exactly am I multiplying here? I've got other examples of this with instructions like `iDiv` and `Div` as well.

Comment: What each instruction does is written in the [instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) (and presumably you also got some course material covering this).

Comment: My professor went "Off the Book" For this, I took notes, but really I can't find any explanation for this kinda thing. Was just looking for a basic run-down on this.

Comment: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mul EBX multiplies the value in EAX with EBX. The lower 32 bits of the result are stored in EAX, the higher 32 bits of the result are stored in EDX.
EAX will be 264 and EDX will be 0.

Mul (+ 32bit register) multiplies EAX with the specified register, stores the the lower 32 bits of the result in EAX and the higher 32 bits in EDX.

Mul (+ 16bit register) multiplies AX with the specified register, stores the the lower 16 bits of the result in AX and the higher 16 bits in DX.

Mul (+ 8bit register) multiplies AL with the specified register and stores the result in AX.